# TypeError: q is undefined (in JS)

Tags: javascript

I have to make a quiz app following instructions from a video. I follow the instructions and make the app. Almost everything works but I get no score at the end of the quiz. The web console shows TypeError in the following part of the code (16th line in bold font):

```
var currentQuestion = 0;
var score = 0;
var totQuestions = questions.length;

var container = document.getElementById('quizContainer');
var questionEl = document.getElementById('question');
var opt1 = document.getElementById('opt1');
var opt2 = document.getElementById('opt2');
var opt3 = document.getElementById('opt3');
var opt4 = document.getElementById('opt4');
var nextButton = document.getElementById('nextButton');
var resultCont = document.getElementById('result');

function loadQuestion (questionIndex) {
var q = questions[questionIndex];
**questionEl.textContent = (questionIndex + 1) + '. ' + q.question;**
opt1.textContent = q.option1;
opt2.textContent = q.option2;
opt3.textContent = q.option3;
opt4.textContent = q.option4;

};
function loadNextQuestion () {
var selectedOption = document.querySelector('input[type=radio]:checked');
if(!selectedOption){
    alert('Please select your answer!');
    return;
}
var answer = selectedOption.value;
if(questions[currentQuestion].answer ==answer){
    score += 10;
}
selectedOption.checked = false;
currentQuestion++;
if(currentQuestion == totQuestions - 1){
    nextButton.textContent = 'Finish';
}
if(currentQuestion == totQuestions){
    container.style.display = 'none';
    resultCont.style.display = '';
    resultCont.textContent = 'Your score: ' + score;
}
loadQuestion(currentQuestion);
}
loadQuestion(currentQuestion);
```

Could anyone please point out the error?
Here is the file on which **questions** is defined:

```
var questions = [{
"question": "Why do we use the present simple tense?",
"option1": "General truths and facts",
"option2": "Complete action",
"option3": "Continuous action",
"option4": "Continuous action linked with past",
"answer": "1"
}, {
"question": "Why do we use the present continuous tense?",
"option1": "General truths and facts",
"option2": "Complete action",
"option3": "Continuous action",
"option4": "Continuous action linked with past",
"answer": "3"
}, {
"question": "Why do we use the present perfect tense?",
"option1": "General truths and facts",
"option2": "Complete action",
"option3": "Continuous action",
"option4": "Continuous action linked with past",
"answer": "2"
}, {
"question": "Why do we use the present perfect continuous tense?",
"option1": "General truths and facts",
"option2": "Complete action",
"option3": "Continuous action",
"option4": "Continuous action linked with past",
"answer": "4"
}]
```

Comment: what is `questions` and where did it come from?

Comment: What is `questions`? What are you passing to the function?

Comment: @Craicerjack I have posted just the error part of the code to avoid my question being put on hold or closed. Should I post the whole code?

Comment: @KaptanSingh if `q` is undefined that means the issue is with the line `var q = questions[questionIndex];` which would point to `questions` being undefined but since you havent told us what that is, its hard to know. You should post the parts that are relevant to the question. Certainly you should post what `questions` is and where its defined and possibly how `loadQuestion` is being called.

Comment: @KaptanSingh if your `questions` variable is undefined, or the index is not present in the array, you get that error :)

Comment: @Craicerjack questions is defined on a separate JS file with a list of questions and answers.

Comment: Show the code. `questions[questionIndex]` must have a `.question` property.

Comment: console.log(`variable`) is your friend... use liberally to debug

Comment: @JohnHascall Thanks. But could you please tell me how it is used? I am new to coding so even most basic things are difficult for a while.

Comment: As the first lines of `loadQuestion()` I would do `console.log(questionIndex);` and `console.log(questions[questionIndex]);` to see what those values are.

Comment: Some hints on seeing console.log for various browsers: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Opening_the_Web_Console https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21491?locale=en_US

Comment: Is the file where `questions` is defined included **before** the other file? What you could also do is add your code to [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and include the link here so we could see it.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, in JS, doing `var myvar = some.thing` does not guarantee you to have a value in `myvar`.

If the `some` variable does not contain a `thing` property, then `some.thing` is `undefined`, so will be `myvar`.

Simple demo [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WRNbpr) (Use the console button in the left bottom). The last line will throw an error in your browser console, cause your cannot do `undefined.someProperty`.